# How to add decoupler to Staging List?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm having a problem with Kerbal Space Program where decouplers are not appearing in the staging list.  Instead they are just to the left of the staging list.  I can click them and drag them but they won't go into the staging list.  Even if I add an empty stage and try to add them to it, no luck.

Comment: Image please? That might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: If you have a "ghost" part in the builder scene (a part that's not connected to the actual craft), its staging icon will appear to the side. I'd hazard a guess that your decoupler currently isn't properly connected to the craft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the decoupler icon appears next to the staging list instead of inside it, it usually means that the decoupler (and also anything attached to it) are not attached to the main vehicle but instead "floating" in the construction building. When this is the case, the decoupler (and anything attached to it) should be rendered slightly transparent.

To attach the decoupler, click it and then place it at a valid connection node. Keep in mind that ring-shaped decouplers can not be attached to any surface, but only to nodes marked with green spheres.

Comment: Except for the radial decouplers, slightly obviously :)

Comment: This is the issue.  The problem is that it's extremely hard to get the decoupler to 'align' properly.  I find I have to move my cursor around a lot to find the exact perfect spot.

Comment: @ShaneC: Hold down `Mod` (Win `Alt`/Mac `Option`) to `Disable surface attach/exclusively use node attach` in the VAB/SPH. http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Key_bindings